# Merge files having same prefix from different directories

Tags: regex, perl

I have written the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

die "usage:$0 <Input_folder_1>\t<Input_folder_2>\t<Out_folder>\t<Project_name>\t\n" unless $#ARGV == 3;

my $folder1 = shift;
#print "$folder1\n";
my $folder2 = shift;
#print "$folder2\n";
my $out = shift;
my $project_name = shift;

my $file1;
my $file2;
my $file3;
my $file4;

#print "$project_name\n";
foreach(glob("$folder1/$project_name\_S[0-9]_R1_001.fastq.gz")){
    chomp;
    #print "Hello World\n";
    $_ =~ m{$folder1/$project_name\_S[0-9]_R1_001\.fastq.gz};
        #print "$_\n";
        $file1 = $_;
        print "$file1\n";
}

foreach(glob("$folder2/$project_name\_S[0-9]_R1_001.fastq.gz")){
    chomp;
    #print "Hello World\n";
    $_ =~ m{$folder2/$project_name\_S[0-9]_R1_001\.fastq.gz};
        #print "$_\n";
        $file2 = $_;
        print "$file2\n";
}
```

`cat $file1 $file2 > $out/$project_name.R1.fastq.gz`; #line 42

```
foreach(glob("$folder1/$project_name\_S[0-9]_R2_001.fastq.gz")){
    chomp;
    #print "Hello World\n";
    $_ =~ m{$folder1/$project_name\_S[0-9]_R2_001\.fastq.gz};
        #print "$_\n";
        $file3 = $_;
        print "$file3\n";
}

foreach(glob("$folder2/$project_name\_S[0-9]_R2_001.fastq.gz")){
    chomp;
    #print "Hello World\n";
    $_ =~ m{$folder2/$project_name\_S[0-9]_R2_001\.fastq.gz};
        #print "$_\n";
        $file4 = $_;
        print "$file4\n";
}

`cat $file3 $file4 > $out/$project_name.R2.fastq.gz`;
```

This script is run as follows:

```
./script.pl folder1 folder2 output_folder project_name
```

when I run this script with following files it runs smoothly

```
folder1/123-abcQ_S3_R1_001.fastq.gz
folder2/123-abcQ_S1_R1_001.fastq.gz
folder1/123-abcQ_S3_R2_001.fastq.gz
folder2/123-abcQ_S1_R2_001.fastq.gz

./script.pl folder1 folder2 out/ 123-abcQ
```

It will merge the files folder1/123-abcQ_S3_R1_001.fastq.gz and folder2/123-abcQ_S1_R1_001.fastq.gz to create a merged 123-abcQ.R1.fastq.gz file in the output directory.

But when I run the same script with following files it gives me an error:

```
folder1/demo-1_S10_R1_001.fastq.gz
folder1/demo-1_S10_R2_001.fastq.gz
folder2/demo-1_S12_R1_001.fastq.gz
folder2/demo-1_S12_R2_001.fastq.gz

./script.pl folder1 folder2 out/ demo-1
```

> Use of uninitialized value $file1 in concatenation (.) or string at
>   ./script.pl line 42. Use of uninitialized value $file2 in
>   concatenation (.) or string at ./script.pl line 42.

I can't figure out how to resolve this. Your adivice will be appreciated.

Comment: Please mark line 42 for us.

Comment: `S[0-9]_` can't match `S10_`, there are two digits, not one.

Comment: Hi, when i modified the regex with [0-9]+ it still gave the same error. with + operator matching one or more digits.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With your second set of arguments you shouldn't see any output before the warning. It doesn't print anything.

That's because it doesn't return any files from your `glob` calls so the `foreach` loop doesn't actually get executed. `$file1` is `undef` initially and now never gets set.

```
my $file1; # starts out as undef
# ...

#print "$project_name\n";
foreach(glob("$folder1/$project_name\_S[0-9]_R1_001.fastq.gz")){ # finds nothing
    chomp;
    #print "Hello World\n";
    $_ =~ m{$folder1/$project_name\_S[0-9]_R1_001\.fastq.gz};
        #print "$_\n";
        $file1 = $_;
        print "$file1\n"; # no output here
}
```

It probably does not find your files because you don't have any files that match the pattern.

There are two things going on here:

- [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) takes [a sort of pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) that can contain [wildcards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character#File_and_directory_patterns). It only returns files that match this pattern. It is **not a regular expression*.
- You are doing a pattern match, and ignore the result.

Let's look at it more closely.

> ```
> foreach(glob("$folder1/$project_name\_S[0-9]_R2_001.fastq.gz")){
> ```

The interesting bit is `glob EXPR`. Your expression is:

```
# | variable interpolation 
# |        | variable interpolation            
# |        |            | treat this as a literal underscore, not part of var name
# |        |            |  one digit out of group 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
# |        |            |  |   |
  $folder1/$project_name\_S[0-9]_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

This will return a list of files that match this pattern. If it finds no files, nothing is returned. The `foreach` loop then iterates that list. Again, if there is nothing in the list, the loop never gets called.

> ```
> foreach ( glob ... ) {
>     chomp;
>     $_ =~ m{$folder1/$project_name\_S[0-9]_R1_001\.fastq.gz};
>     $file1 = $_;
> ```

You now cut off a newline with `chomp`. That doesn't make any sense, because filenames do not usually have a newline at the end.

You then do a pattern match on the filename with the same pattern that you used for your `glob`. In this context, it is an actual regular expression, so some characters have special meanings.

```
m{
  $folder1        # variable interpolation
  /               # literal slash /
  $project_name   # variable interpolation
  \_S             # literal backslash \ and S
  [0-9]           # one digit from 0 to 9
  _R1_001         # literal string
  \.              # literal dot .
  fastq           # literal string
  .               # exactly one of any character
  gz              # literal string
};
```

As you can see, the pattern means something entirely different. You have escaped one of the dots `.`, but not both.

But it does not matter, because this operation does not do anything. **You just throw the result away!**

You then assign `$_` to `$file1`, regardless of a match or not.

---

I think it would make more sense to just get all gzipped files in that directory and then check them.

```
foreach my $filename ( glob <$folder1/${project_name}*.fastq.gz> ) {
    if ( $filename =~ m{
            /             # separates the folder from the filename
            $project_name # anchor to project
            _         
            [0-9]+        # one or more numbers (001, 123, 9, ...)
            _R1_001 
            \.fastq\.gz   # file type
            $             # end of string
        }x
     ) {
        $file1 = $filename;
        last;
    }
}
```

This uses the other `glob` syntax, which I find more readable, gets all files in `$folder1` that start with the `$project_name` and end in `.fastq.gz`. It then iterates the list of files and performs a pattern match to make sure we actually get the right files. I've included the `/x` modifier to ignore whitespace in the pattern, so we can have comments.

Note the `[0-9]+`, which says one or more numbers. That's important so files with numbers higher than 9 are found.

Once a match is found, it assigns `$file1` and then exits the loop with [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html).

You might want to also add a check before you run your external command that uses `$file1` and `$file2`.

```
if ($file1 && $file2) {
     `cat $file1 $file2 > $out/$project_name.R1.fastq.gz`
} else {
     print "No matches found for first set of files.";
}
```

Comment: so why does it work for other files? can you please tell how to fix this?

Comment: @Callie I cannot answer that, because I don't know what files you have there. Start by looking into your `$folder1` directory and list all files that are there, then see if they match your pattern. Maybe getting all files in that folder and taking only the ones you need with a pattern match is a better idea. Certainly easier to debug.

Comment: I tried using different expressions with the regex I am using. e.g [0-9][0-9] will match demo-1_S10_R1_001.fastq.gz but it will fail for sampleA_S2_R1_001.fastq.gz. I need to modify foreach(glob("$folder1/$project_name\_S[0-9]_R1_001.fastq.gz so that it work for both S10 and S2 as well. I have tried [0-9]+ and [0-9][0-9]? but both fail. Can you suggest any modification?

Comment: I modified the regex to [0-9]* and it's working for both S10 and S2 as well.

Comment: @Callie you are **not** using a regular expression. You are using a _wildcard_ for `glob`. Those are two fundamentally different things that just happen to share some similar syntax. `[0-9]*` in the pattern for `glob` does not mean _lots of numbers, but at least none_, it means _a number, followed by anything, possibly lots of anything or nothing_.

Comment: @Callie see my updated answer. I think that should explain what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. How should I approach this problem without using the argument project_name. As I have 100's of files in folder1 and folder2 and each time giving project name is cumbersome. Is there a way in which to match filenames in folder1 and folder2 and if a match is found perform concatenation without giving project_name and processing 100s of files at a time? How can I approach this?

Comment: @Callie I don't fully understand what you are trying to do. Do you just want to merge all files, or is it always pairs?

Comment: It is always in pairs. e.g folder1 contains SampleA_S10_R1_001.fastq.gz, SampleA_S10_R2_001.fastq.gz, SampleB_S2_R1_001.fastq.gz, SampleB_S2_R2_001.fastq.gz. folder2 contains SampleA_S12_R1_001.fastq.gz, SampleA_S12_R2_001.fastq.gz, SampleB_S3_R1_001.fastq.gz, SampleB_S3_R2_001.fastq.gz.

Comment: @Callie then you should probably write your program to find pairs and do all of them, and just tell it which folders to use. Why call it manually? Just automate it anyway. It's really just an additional loop.

Comment: So to merge R1 files for SampleA(folder1) with R1 files for SampleB(folder2) and merge R2 files for SampleA(folder1) with R2 files for SampleA(folder2). Same with SampleB without having to specify SampleA and SampleB

Comment: @Ca If you can describe your pattern in code, you can make this work automatically. I don't understand what the relation between those files it, it's really hard to read this in comments here. Essentially, you want to read all the files in the first folder, and for every file check if there is a matching file in the second folder. If there is, you do your stuff to it and write out the new file somewhere. You might also want to check if the new file already exists first so you don't overwrite it (or do double work). You can also add debug info to say when it can't find a second file.